# Gmail Notifier using 287Mb of RAM

Tags: gmail

It's currently up to 308Mb of RAM.

[image: Gmail Notifier]

Is this normal behaviour?  Should I be concerned?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The notifier is using more memory that Firefox itself, and also appears to be eating your CPU. Have you considered using an integrated Firefox add-on instead, such as [Webmail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webmail-notifier/)?

Comment: @Paul Lammertsma: Thanks, I'll use that instead.  Why didn't you make your comment an answer?

Comment: I didn't really consider it a resolution to your problem, but more of a workaround. But since it appears Google stopped developing it, you're pretty much forced to switch to something else. I've posted an answer so that it may benefit others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be something inherently wrong with the [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html) as it is using much too much memory and is also eating your CPU cycles. Google last updated it back in 2006, and it might not be compatible with the latest versions of Firefox anymore.

I would suggest using an integrated Firefox add-on instead, such as [Webmail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webmail-notifier/).

Comment: Chrome has it built-in, surely FF does this too?

Comment: No, Firefox doesn't come bundled with any such functionality. The reason Chrome might include this out-of-the-box is because the browser itself is a Google product. An alternative solution for Firefox 4 may be to keep a Gmail tab open and pinned; it will light up when new e-mail is received.

Comment: Oh well, hopefully soon. http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebNotifications/publish/

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some kind of memory leak, which is a problem with the application itself. I would use an integrated addon like @Paul Lammertsma said.